# Get conflict line/range

Tags: git

Is it possible to get which line numbers conflict? i.e, the lines between the `<<<<<<<`, `=======` and `>>>>>>>` markers.
if I have the following file:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
master
=======
develop
>>>>>>> develop
```

`git some command` and the output will be some data about files and **line numbers** in conflict?

**Edit:**

File master:

```
1. shared
2. 
3. master
4. 
5. shared
```

File develop:

```
1. shared
2. 
3. develop
4. 
5. shared
```

File merge:

```
1. shared
2. 
3. <<<<<<< HEAD
4. master
5. =======
6. develop
7. >>>>>>> develop
8. 
9. shared
```

run `git diff`:

```
diff --cc test.txt
index cf590df,7415cb0..0000000
--- a/test.txt
+++ b/test.txt
@@@ -1,5 -1,5 +1,9 @@@
  shared

++<<<<<<< HEAD
 +master
++=======
+ develop
++>>>>>>> develop

  shared
```

Desired output is something like:

```
Master 3 - 3
Develop 3 - 3
Merged 3 - 7
```

- I.e for each conflict what are the line ranges..
- The merged one is bonus.. =)

Comment: What if there was another conflict above it? How would it know what line numbers they should be?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you, but by how many \r\n chars in file..

Answer (score 4):

When you run `git diff` in a conflicted state, you will get a special diff format called *Combined diff format*. I added a second line in the `develop` branch for clarity. It looks like this:

```
$ git diff
diff --cc foo
index 1f7391f,1e25601..0000000
--- a/foo
+++ b/foo
@@@ -1,1 -1,2 +1,6 @@@
++<<<<<<< HEAD
 +master
++=======
+ develop
+ second line
++>>>>>>> develop
```

The line beginning with `@@@` shows the ranges for each of the three files, that is in this case the file on `master`, `develop`, and the file with the conflict markers.

```
@@@ -1,1 -1,2 +1,6 @@@
    |    |    |
    |    |     - file with conflict markers
    |     - develop
     - master
```

More information in section `COMBINED DIFF FORMAT` of [man git-diff](https://gitirc.eu/git-diff.html#_combined_diff_format).

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure I totally understand. How I can know which line numbers (range..) the conflict in.. sorry if I wasn't clear, but I want the line numbers (in your example: in master the conflicts lines are 1 and in develop 1-2)

Comment: `@@@ -1,1 -1,2 +1,6 @@@` tells you this. `-1,1` means `1` line from and including line `1`. `-1,2` means `2` lines from and including line `1`. `+1,6`, `6` lines (conflict markers included) from and including line `1`.

Comment: Thanks jsageryd, I'm feeling idiot :O, I edited my question with a more specific example, from your answer I understand that the first number note from which line the conflict start and the second note how many lines in conflict... but this is not settled with my last example in my edited question

Comment: Would you mind adding to your question the desired output?

Comment: Desired output added to the question

Comment: Ah! Now I understand what you want. Sorry for my misunderstanding. I don't know of a way to find this info, perhaps the man page can give some hints? Normally I would try to experiment to find an answer but I'm out travelling at the moment without access to a computer so there is not much I can contribute with further. Apologies.

Comment: My fault! you were right! By default `git diff` is run with `-U3` which means it takes three lines from before and after of the conflict to give you a "context", but if run `git diff -U0` it gives me exactly the conflict range. It would be great if you will edit your answer and I'll check it :)

Comment: The ranges (`@@@ ...`) refer to the whole diff output, including context, so if the conflict is the only thing in the diff, maybe your reasoning is right. I don't know if there is a right way to do this or if the way you describe will work in all cases; I would probably grep for the conflict markers to find the line numbers.